# Error while installing maven on Windows

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have downloaded apache-maven-3.0.4 and installed. I have referred below link for it.

```
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-maven-and-how-do-i-install-it.html?page=1
```

But when I entered the command "mvn install", I am getting errors as:

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Users\admin). Please verify you invoked Maven from the co
rrect directory. -> [Help 1]
```

I downloaded the maven-clean-plugin-2.3 JAR file and putted it into .m2/repository/

I explore on internet for pom file but I failed to find it.

From where do I find the pom file for maven-clean-plugin?

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: Have you also read *the second page* (http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-maven-and-how-do-i-install-it.html?page=2) of that tutorial?

Comment: yes I read it. In that it showing that while "mvn clean" is executed then it is downloading those files which are mentioned (http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-maven-and-how-do-i-install-it.html?page=2). But in my case it is not downloading. Is anything wrong with me?

Comment: This command requires to have a maven project in the current folder with a valid pom.xml file in it. It does not ne seem to be the case here. That's why maven complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `mvn install` starts default lifecycle (up to `install` phase) on the current project that is POM (describing that project) must be in the current directory. As Maven says, there is no `pom.xml` file in your `C:\Users\admin` directory.

And about your question title: it seems that you've successfully installed Maven ;).